# No need for creating Short objects explicitly?

Tags: java

Following code works perfect and adds 1 and 2 values to the list, but why?
Why you don't need to create Short objects explicitly? e.g: `list.add(new Short(1));`

```
List<Short> list = new ArrayList();
list.add((short)1);
list.add((short)2);
System.out.println(list);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is called [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html). It is a feature that automatically converts primitives to their corresponding object type. It is present since Java 1.5.

The opposite of autoboxing is called autounboxing but beware of NullPointerException

Comment: +1 for the warning about NPEs. To make it explicit: `list.add(null); short s = list.get(0);` The get will essentially compile down to `((Short)list.get(0)).shortValue()`, which will get a `null`, cast it to `Short`, and throw a NPE on `shortValue()`.

Answer (score 1):

This is called autoboxing.

Note that it will still create true `Short` objects automatically, and these occupy 16 bytes on your heap, the same as an Integer object. Only native `short` values only occupy 2 bytes (but cannot be put into `java.util.collections`).

In many situations

```
list.put((short) 12345);
list.put((short) 12345);
```

will in fact even create *two* such objects, i.e. 32 bytes plus the memory occupied by the list object. The pointers stored in the list already occupy 4-8 bytes each.

If you have just a few instances that is okay. If you have several millions this can impact performance badly because of memory management and use. With raw shorts you usually can go 10 times as far before becoming slow or running out of memory.

Comment: I'd say that typically, you probably need more than "thousands" in order to run into significant performance issues